# How to run change detection when a function in bind in template?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

In my template, I have bind a function that returns a value to be displayed in the view. But, due to the change detection that runs in the background, I am forced to add some extra unnecessary handling. If the data was being bind by some property then I would have added `changeDetector.detectChanges()` in the right place but this being a function where I am returning the value that should be displayed(which is where I would have added the code to run change detection), it is not possible to run change detection manually. So, how can I run detect changes inside of a function that returns a value?
Here is the code:

template.html

```
<li #itemElement
    *ngFor="let item of currentData; let i = index;"
    class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix p-1 line-h-0">
    <input
      type="checkbox"/>
    <label>
      {{ textAccessor(item) == 'null' ? '(Blanks)' : textAccessor(item) }}
    </label>
    </div>
  </li>
```

component.ts

```
protected textAccessor = (dataItem: any) => {
    if (dataItem !== undefined && this.field in dataItem) {
      if (typeof dataItem === 'string' || typeof dataItem === 'number') {
        return dataItem;
      } else if (dataItem == null || dataItem[this.field] == null) {
        return 'null';
      } else {
        return dataItem[this.field];
      }
    }
  }
```

The `currentData` in the template is the data coming from a service. I want to run change detection inside of `textAccessor()`

Comment: Why exactly do you need to call change detection? What happens if you let Angular run it automatically? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to optimize my component

Comment: This is not a good practice to bind a function in your template. You should rather calculate your labels before displaying them.